How to hide helper definitions in d.ts files from the rest of the project?
I finally learned about the posibility of creating type script definitions for plain JS using .d.ts files. These are imported globally, which is great for defining JSON types and the like.
However, all of them are imported globally. So if I have a helper type that is used as a part of bigger definition, it will polute the entire project.
For example:
type PrimitiveValues = string | number | boolean;
type PromitiveRecord = Record<string, PrimitiveValues>;

In this case, I might not need PrimitiveValues explicitly visible. Is it possible to omit these helper symbols?

Why do you think "it will pollute the entire project"? If PrimitiveValues is not visible, how can you tell what PromitiveRecord is exactly? Even if you don't use it explicitly, what harm dose it cause to you?

No, it's not possible to exclude select symbols from compilation. In order to selectively expose certain symbols, you can use Namespaces and Modules as described in the TypeScript handbook. Generally, using modules and importing the desired types in each module is the correct approach for modular code.
